# Upload File Geodatabase without Server, Credit Usage?

Tags: arcgis-online, file-geodatabase, arcgis-collector, pricing

- Instead of going through a server to publish an arcgis web service hosted layer, I want to go right from my local machine to AGOL so that my server is NEVER exposed.
- I want to eventually put this File GDB into Collector.
- I have credits to use, but not many.

I zipped the .gdb and uploaded it to my content.  I then want to publish it, but before I do this how many credits will it use and will it reuse credits everytime I overwrite? What is the best way to manage a GDB (I need to coded value domains) in AGOL so I can access it on Collector, WITHOUT using a server?

Comment: Steps are different. Create map mxd using fcs from fgdb. Assign symbology etc. Share map as feature service. In agol add to new map with full editing. Polish map, e.g. configure pop ups, show hide fields. Save map.  Domains will work in collector. With 100 points you can do decent work. Disable analysis , route find. They eat credits, storage next to nothing

Comment: @FelixIP thank you for your advice, although not quite articulate.  I was able to find better resources to answer my question and will post solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My original question stemmed from my trials and errors. I wanted to know the credit usage because I tried to publish the FGDB one way and CVDs were not transferring for some reason.  I have since found the reason that the CVDs did not publish (a bug of course). I have also found a solution.  **I have also found that this whole process is costing me essentially no credits (less than one).**

3. Once the DB was ready for field collection, it was published as a service to AGOL

a. **ArcMap 10.2 has a bug**. There are multiple ways to publish an entire database as a hosted service from the desktop to AGOL, however you have to do it one specific way in order for the coded value domains to upload properly. The steps are as follows:

i. Add all data to be published to ArcMap, remove all data that should not be published from ArcMap

ii. Symbolize everything appropriately

iii. BEFORE YOU PUBLISH: follow best practice for publishing and sharing on AGOL http://video.esri.com/watch/1702/arcgis-online-best-practices-for-publishing-and-sharing Some key points include:

1. Finalize schema
2. Make sure data is in Web Mercator Auxiliary Sphere projection
3. Be sure to include robust metadata

iv. Sign into AGOL from ArcMap: File> Sign In

v. Share as a service: File> Share As > Service

vi. Follow instructions in box depending on the database requirements

1. For this particular project, I shared as a feature service with ALL editing capabilities

vii. From AGOL, sign in and navigate to the feature service in Content

viii. Edit the feature service to allow editing, delete protection, sync, and any other custom options necessary.

1. For this particular project, I allowed all editing, exportation, sync, and tracking edits

ix. Add feature service to map

1. Test to be sure that all CVDs work and that the feature service handles edits properly.
2. The feature service hosted on AGOL is now a separate entity from the database it was published from. In order to edit the feature service on AGOL, follow these steps:

a. Sign into AGOL from ArcMap: File> Sign In

b. Open the Catalog and navigate to My Hosted Feature Services

c. Add feature service to map

d. List the table of contents by drawing order

e. Right-click on the feature service name > Edit Features > Create Local Copy for Editing

f. Edit Features